# How to read a file and open each link via Google Chrome

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read each link from `urls.txt` and then open each link in Google Chrome. Here is `urls.txt`:

```
https://httpbin.org
https://example.com
https://google.com
https://facebook.com
```

This code is working as expected:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" https://httpbin.org/
```

This is how I am reading each link but something is missing here, not sure what. Can anyone let me know what am I missing?

> condition: If link starts with https only then open a link via Google Chrome

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  if [[ $line == 'https' ]]; then
    open -a Google\ Chrome "$line"
    echo "Opened: $line"
    sleep 0.3
  fi
done < urls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if [[ $line == 'https' ]]
> ```

This checks if `$line` is *exactly* `https`. To check if it *starts with* `https` add a `*` wildcard:

```
if [[ $line == 'https'* ]]
```